# PHP/Kohana - avoiding repeating code to check if a user is logged in

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I am a newbie to  PHP/Kohana application development.

In the web app i am developing , whenever a new request come to the controller i am required to check if the user is logged-in or is he having sufficient privileges to commit the action he requested. Since my application have different category of members(having different degree of authority), every controller method ends up having multitude of if/else branches. the code is repeated in other controller methods as well.

Is there any suggested way to centralize these calls and to avoid code repetition? I mean is the only way to achieve this by writing a method to encompass all the user session code ? or am i missing any functionality that is baked into the  PHP/Kohana which is already dealing this scenario?

eg:-

```
if (Auth::instance()->logged_in('commentator')) {

// do something here.

}
else if (Auth:instance()->logged_in('admin')){

// do something here.

}
else if (Auth:instance()->logged_in('reviewer')){

// do something here.

}
```

Comment: So different groups share the same methods and controllers? If so, you'll always have to do a check just because of the design. Why not let different controllers handle different groups?

Comment: Are you suggesting that of having a main controller , and this main controller route calls to the sub controllers after checking the role?in that case, should i also have different view files to cater different set of users?

Comment: This could make sense here, yes. Also use inheritence so you need to write as little code as possible. It all depends on how much the actions differ. This shouldn't concern the views, as they shouldn't worry who calls them what for, but simply look good ;) I'll think about this more and should be able to give you a complex answer tonight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a controller named `Controller_Authenticated` with some code like this:

```
protected $login_level;

public function before()
{
    parent::before();

    if (Auth::instance()->logged_in('commentator')) {
        $this->login_level = 'commentator';
    }
    elseif (Auth:instance()->logged_in('admin')){
        $this->login_level = 'admin';
    }
    elseif (Auth:instance()->logged_in('reviewer')){
        $this->login_level = 'reviewer';
    }
    else {
        // Redirect to login page here, or display a "you are not logged in" message
    }
}
```

Then, have your other controllers extend `Controller_Authenticated` instead of just `Controller`.  Then you can check the value of `parent::$login_level` to see what kind of user this is.

That way, all of your login-checking code is in one place, and checking what kind of user you are is done automatically when the controller loads (before the action is called).

The [Kohana documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/mvc/controllers#before-and-after) has almost exactly this example for using a `before` method to handle login stuff.

Comment: If you extend a `Controller_Template` eg it is important to call `parent::before();` first thing in your own method

Comment: Since it doesn't hurt to have the call to `parent::before` in any case, i added it to my example.